# Content model failled when dynamic deploying

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I have this contentModel file located in alfresco models repository.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model name="swTl:TresCompletModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
    <imports>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0" prefix="bpm"/>
    </imports>

     <namespaces>
            <namespace uri="starxpert.TresCompletModel.fr" prefix="swTl"/>
      </namespaces>

      <types>
            <type name="swTl:debut">
            <parent>bpm:activitiOutcomeTask</parent>
               <properties>
                 <property name="swTl:dateDebut">
                     <title>Date de debut de vaccances</title>
                     <type>d:date</type>
                     <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                 </property>

                <property name="swTl:dateFin">
                   <title>Date fin de vaccances</title>
                   <type>d:date</type>   
                   <mandatory>true</mandatory>                                                   
                </property>
               </properties>
             </type>  
       </types>
<model>
```

I tried to dynamically deploy this model by setting the `model active` property to true, but i still getting this error in alfresco logs:

```
2017-08-29 18:13:57,528  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] [http-bio-8080-exec-29] Exception from executeScript: 07290005 Failed to parse model

org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 07290005 Failed to parse model

Caused by: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Expected "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0}model" end tag, found "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0}model" start tag (line 80, col 61)
```

Is there anybody who did this before ? Thanks for any hlep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you end your model with `</model>`, as opposed to `<model>`?